# Force CVS repository to work "silently" all the time

Tags: cvs

When I use commands like `cvs commit -m .` I get rather annoying info that cvs is examining all directories.
To avoid it I can use `cvs -q commit -m .`
Can I do something so that cvs works *silently* for all operations without the option `-q`?

Comment: You can use an alias or a function for `cvs`, eg `alias cvs=$(which cvs) -q` or `cvs() { $(which cvs) -q "$@"; } ; export cvs`. An alias is valid for interactive commands in the current shell, while an exported function will work in subshells, including those created to run scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, although I used `alias cvs="cvs -q"` instead of `alias cvs=$(which cvs) -q` as it threw error...thanks again

Comment: Using `which cvs` forces reference to the real binary file, bypassing any internal definitions, such as an alias or function. This stops any possibility of recursion.

Comment: I have submitted an answer, so that others with a similar problem can see that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias or a function for `cvs`, eg:

```
alias cvs="$(which cvs) -q"
cvs() { $(which cvs) -q "$@"; } ; export cvs
```

An alias is valid for interactive commands in the current shell, while an exported function will work in subshells, including those created to run scripts.

Using `which cvs` forces reference to the real binary file, bypassing any internal definitions, such as an alias or function. This stops any possibility of recursion. Note that using double quotes in the alias definition means that `which cvs` is called only once, when the alias is defined; single quotes would call `which cvs` whenever `cvs` is typed.

Comment: But `alias cvs=$(which cvs) -q` throws error:-
`-bash: alias: -q: not found`

Comment: @SohamBanerjee - Sorry, missed quotes.